# Elimination set for the term algebra in A Shorter Model Theory

Tags: proof-explanation, model-theory, quantifier-elimination

I'm reading Hodges' A Shorter Model Theory.
In the section about quantifier elimination, theorem $2.7.5$ proves that some set of formulas is an elimination set of the term algebra (under a different signature).
I don't understand this passage:

> We claim $T_2$ implies that for any $k$ elements $(k > 0) $ there is
> an element distinct from all of them which satisfies $\text{Is}_F(y)$.
> By $(6.15)$, $T_2$ implies that if $\text{Is}_F(x_0)$ then there is a
> unique $x_1$ such that $\text{Is}_F(x_1)$ and $F_i(x_1) = x_0$ for all
> $i < n$; by $(6.18)$, $x_0 \neq x_1$. Likewise by $(6.15)$ there is
> $x_2$ such that $\text{Is}_F(x_2)$ and $F_i(x_2) =x_1$ for all $i < n$, and then by $(6.18)$ again, $x_2 \neq x_1$ and $x_2 \neq x_1$. Etc.
> etc.; this proves the claim. With $(6.16)$, the claim allows the
> reduction to $(7.10)$, unless the problem is to eliminate the
> quantifier from $\exists\ y\ \text{Is}_F(y)$. When $L_1$ has at least
> one constant $c$, the formula $\exists\ y\ \text{Is}_F(y)$ reduces to
> $\neg\bot$ by $(6.15)$; but in general it is equivalent to $\beta$.

I don't understand how the claim is proven and how it implies said reduction

Here are pictures of the relevant pages for context.

The term algebra:

> [image]

Theorem 2.7.5:

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Your question should be accessible on its own, without requiring the reader to have a copy of Hodges nearby. So: what term algebra (for what signature) are we considering? What is $T_2$? What is $\mathrm{Is}_F(y)$? What is $\beta$? Etc

Comment: @AlexKruckman I provided context.